# Cannot open existing Cordova project

Tags: cordova, mobile

We have an mobile application built with Cordova and am struggling to open or get it to run.

I'm stuck and have spent a day reading tutorials but so far no progress.

I have the following folders.

.idea
gen
hooks
platforms
plugins
www

I've tried the Cordova command line tools.
I've tried opening in Android Studio.
I've tried opening in Visual Studio.

Comment: what i ll do in your case : create new project cordova with all plugins needed. then try to open this project in android studio, if it work, just copy your www folder and adapt manifest and config files , then clean project. after that you ll be able to open project and run simulator and at least see errors

Comment: I tried doing this, without much luck.

Comment: how many plugins ? it s ionic or pure cordova ? the new project without changing files is open well ?

Comment: 11 plugins and is cordova only. How should I edit/debug this project? In Android Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: the best to debug android, still android studio. 11 plugins are install very fast, so create new project with all 11 plugins and then the project ll be available to be open.